# Let $H = \{2^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ & define a relation $R$ on the set $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ of positive rationals by $a\mathbin{R}b$ iff $a/b \in H$.

Tags: proof-verification, relations, exponentiation, rational-numbers

Let $H = \{2^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and define a relation $R$ on the set $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$ of positive rational numbers by $a\mathbin{R}b$ if and only if $a/b \in H$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$.

So far I have:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Q^{+}}$. Then $x\mathbin{R}y$ if and only if $\frac{x}{y} \in H$. Then $\frac{x}{y} = 2^{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\frac{x}{x} = 1$. Then, $\frac{x}{y} = 2^{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $\frac{y}{x} = 2^{-m}$.

I'm not sure what to do next or how to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Q^{+}}$.

Comment: In proper MathJax usage the entire expression $H = \{2^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ should be within just one pair of dollar signs.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, I wasn't sure if it would keep the curly brackets if I didn't break it up with the dollar signs because it didn't in the past.

Comment: You need to show $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. $\qquad$

Comment: Look at the MathJax code: H = \{2^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\} $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most of the work, you just need to prove transitivity.

If $a R b$ and $b R c$, $\frac{a}{b}=2^{m_1}$ and $\frac{b}{c}=2^{m_2}$,

multiply them together, you have

$$\frac{a}{c}=2^{m_1+m_2}$$

Since $m_1+m_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{a}{c} \in H$, i.e. $a Rc$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Q^+}$. Then $xRy$ if $\frac{x}{y} \in H$ so $\frac{x}{y}=2^m$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Reflexive:** If $y=x$, then $\frac{x}{x}=1=2^0$. Since $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $R$ is reflexive.

**Symmetrical:** Since $\frac{x}{y}=2^m$, $\frac{y}{x}=2^{-m}$. Since $-m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $R$ is symmetrical.

**Transitive:** If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $\frac{x}{y}=2^m$ and $\frac{y}{z}=2^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $(\frac{x}{y})(\frac{y}{z})=\frac{x}{z}=2^{m+n}$. Since $m+n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{x}{z}\in H$ and so $R$ is transitive.